# Python/Sage "Unable to coerce I to an integer" Error

Tags: python, sage

My program (at this stage) is trying to use newtons method on a function with complex roots (z^3=2). My code looks like this:

```
f(z)=(z^3-2)
p(z)= f(z)-(f(z)/diff(f(z),z))
```

Where p(z) is Newton's Method

```
var('q')
i==1
q[i]=z
    for i in range (0,9):
        q[i+1]=p(q[i])
        print q[i+1]
```

And the error I'm getting is:

```
TypeError: Unable to coerce I to an integer
```

But I don't need it to make I an integer. How do I tell it that, or is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a typo in your code. You want `i=1` instead of `i==1`.

Comment: when I changed that I got other errors, but thank you for getting rid of the most annoying one